# R: Dynamic scoping with eval and functions

Tags: r, eval, scoping

I'm relatively new to dynamic scoping with R and have run into some issues with using eval to change the scope/environment where my own defined function executes.

First, I create a simple environment:

```
> e1 <- new.env(environment())
> e1$a <- 10;
> e1
<environment: 0x5a187a8>
```

Then, I tested eval with ls():

```
> evalq (ls(), e1)
[1] "a"
> evalq (print(a), e1)
[1] 10
```

So far so good.

Then, I define 2 sample functions:

```
g <- function () {
    b <- 20;
    print (ls());
}

h <- function() {
    print (environment());
    print (parent.env(environment()));
    NULL;
}
```

and I try to eval them in the context of e1

```
> eval (g(), e1)
[1] "b"

> eval (h(), e1)
<environment: 0x53a1a68>
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

It seems that both g and h are NOT evaluated in e1 - as environment printed within h is different from that of e1.

Would be great if you can point out what am I missing.

Many thanks!

Comment: `eval` and dynamic scoping are two different things.

Comment: R uses lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not understand the problem. Inside the g()-function you asked for the items in the local environment and got "b" output to the console as a side effect of `print(`). It didn't need to look in 'e1' since its local environment was even "closer". Then you got "b" as the value returned from `print` and it was printed as part of the implicit REPL. Again when you evaluated h() , it reported the environments as of the time of the function's definition. That's lexical scoping.

Comment: My apology for not being clear. What I was trying to do was to access the environment e1 from within g and h (like the behavior of ls). What would be the right way to do it?